# Assign Different Types to Python List in Advance

Tags: list, python-3.x

My apologies if this may have been asked before but I'm very new to Python. I have a file containing data records similar to the following;

K;    0; 710; 85; 2; 2013:12:04:13:11:36.291;  0.0000; 1;1009.3000;  0;
K;    0; 710; 85; 3; 2013:12:04:13:11:36.291;  0.0000; 1;1009.3000;  0;
K;   17; 718; 86; 1; 2013:12:04:13:11:36.198; 995.6880; 4; 0.0000;  0; 0.0000;  280; 0.0000;  576; 0.0000;  904;
K;   17; 718; 86; 2; 2013:12:04:13:11:36.198;  0.0000; 4;1484.0000;  0;1484.0000;  280;1484.0000;  576;1481.6000;  904;

The records are varying length but I am only interested in the first eight items in each record. The items in each record are delimited with the ";" character and varying numbers of space characters.
As I read the file, I would like to assign each line to a list but I would also  like to define the items in the list to have the correct type, e.g. str, int, int, int, int, datetime, float, int etc. At present I am using the following code;

```
def file_extract(pathfile):  
    file = open(pathfile)  
    contents = file.read()  
    # remove spaces and split data based on ';' and \n  
    data_list = [lines.replace(" ","").split(";") for lines in contents.split("\n")]  
    for line in data_list:  
        if line[0] == "K":  
            listraw=line[:9]  
            listraw[1]=int(line[1])  
            listraw[2]=int(line[2])  
            # continue setting types in the listraw[] etc. etc.
```

Unfortunately, as I read the each record from the file contents into a list, all of the items in the list are automatically assigned to string values similar to the following;
'K'    '0' '710' '85' '2' '2013:12:04:13:11:36.291'....
I then have to go through each individual item of the list to set the type as I wish. Is there a more elegant way of setting the individual types in the list?

Comment: No, Python cannot tell from your data what it is "supposed" to be. You will just have to cast it to whatever type is appropriate.

Comment: OK thanks. In this sort of situation, does Python always assign "unknowns" to be string types?

Comment: No... they stay whatever type they were when they came in. They are strings because you read the from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the datatypes in a list and then match them with the fields using `zip`. Something like this:

```
import datetime

# write a parser for the timepoints
def dateparser(string):
    # guessed the dateformat
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S.%f')

# From your code `if line[0] == 'K'` I assume that 'K' is a key for the
# datatypes in the corresponding row.

# For every rowtype you define the datatypes here, where datatype
# is equivalent to a parser. Just make sure it accepts a string and returns the
# type you need.
# I guessed the types here so it works with your example.
parsers = {'K': [str,int,int,int,int,dateparser,float,int,float]}

# the example content
contents = """K; 0; 710; 85; 2; 2013:12:04:13:11:36.291; 0.0000; 1;1009.3000; 0;
K; 0; 710; 85; 3; 2013:12:04:13:11:36.291; 0.0000; 1;1009.3000; 0;
K; 17; 718; 86; 1; 2013:12:04:13:11:36.198; 995.6880; 4; 0.0000; 0; 0.0000; 280; 0.0000; 576; 0.0000; 904;
K; 17; 718; 86; 2; 2013:12:04:13:11:36.198; 0.0000; 4;1484.0000; 0;1484.0000; 280;1484.0000; 576;1481.6000; 904; """

data = []
# the right way for doing this with a file would be:
# with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
#     for line in f:
for line in contents.split('\n'):
    # skip empty lines
    if not line.strip():
        continue

    # first split then strip, feels safer this way...
    fields = [f.strip() for f in line.split(';')]

    # select the parserlist from our dict
    parser_list = parsers[fields[0]]

    # Now match the fields with their parsers, it will automatically stop
    # when there is no parser left. This means if you have 8 parsers only 8
    # fields will be evaluated and the rest is ignored.
    # Comes in handy when the lengths of your row types differ.
    # However it this also goes the other way around. If there 
    # are less fields than parsers, the last parsers will be
    # ignored. If you don't want this to happen you have to
    # make sure that len(fields) >= len(parser_list)
    data.append([parser(field) for parser, field in zip(parser_list, fields)])

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

Prints:

```
['K', 0, 710, 85, 2, datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 4, 13, 11, 36, 291000), 0.0, 1, 1009.3]
['K', 0, 710, 85, 3, datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 4, 13, 11, 36, 291000), 0.0, 1, 1009.3]
['K', 17, 718, 86, 1, datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 4, 13, 11, 36, 198000), 995.688, 4, 0.0]
['K', 17, 718, 86, 2, datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 4, 13, 11, 36, 198000), 0.0, 4, 1484.0]
```

Comment: This works for me except the line  "if line.strip().isempty():" Should this be "if not line.strip():" instead?

Comment: @JC_RMB `continue` skips the rest and continues with the next iteration. You want to skip if line is empty, therefore everything is fine.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it checks and skips empty lines. However, I was wondering about the .isempty() function contained in the original code. Is this an in-built Python function because my IDE doesn't seem to recognize it?

Comment: @JC_RMB you're right... I only saw the `not` and completely missed that you removed `isempty`. I have to admit I don't know why but I was 100% sure that strings would have this method.